# Generate DDL (Create) in SSIS from an Input Source

Tags: sql-server, postgresql, ssis, odbc, ddl

Suppose you have an Source Component and you are doing a simple One-to-One data load to a Desination Component. A Sample screenshot is as below:

[image: A Sample Source to Destination Data load component]

Now when i open my Destination component, i find that it asks me to enter the name of the table where the data would be loaded.

[image]

In the dropdown, i find that the names of the table are getting populated which are already present in my database.

My queries are as below:

1. Do i need to manually create the tables in the database first and then only i can execute the data flow?
2. Is there any way, i could get the all the Source columns and generate a DDL statement to create the table, if required. I am NOT asking for dynamically creating a table. Just a possible solution to get all you input columns and data-types lists and then auto-generate a sample DDL or SQL query.? *(Imagine a scenario where in you have 200-500 columns in a text file/flat file,, manually creating a table with all the columns gets tough)*

*N.B: Integration Tools like Pentaho Kettle provides you with a similar feature. You don't have to worry about table creation. If its not present, you can use kettle feature to create one in the database.*

It would be really helpful if anyone can help me in this. I am also a newbie to SSIS. Not much of a knowledge. Thanks :)

Comment: In case of OLD-DB destination there will a New button. Clicking on it will create table structure in destination automatically. But here you are using ODBC, so are you importing data into ms-acess?

Comment: no i am importing data to Postgresql database... Oh yes... i do find a NEW button in OLEDB driver and it generated me a DDL query as required? Thank @bmsqldev for this.. but why is it not available in ODBC sources?